# How do I submit an app to the App Store review process when the app requires a 1 time 4 digit login code

Tags: ios, app-store

Hi I am submitting a new app to the Apple App Store. As part of the app a login is required. This is done by typing in your mobile number and a 1 time 4 digit code is texted to the user to type into the app to log in. How do I add this to the submission, as when the reviewer types in the provided number the 4 digit code will be texted to our dev device. How do I get around this so it can be reviewed.

Comment: Why would the code be texted to ***your dev device*** and not to the reviewer's device?

Comment: as we don't have the number of the reviewer, if we can get that we can add them to the db, then it would be text to the reviewer

Comment: Your question is really outside the scope of Stack Overflow, but... are you saying users must have registered their phone number with you somewhere else before they can use your app? Sounds like it would be tough to get that approved anyway. In general, though, you either need to provide the reviewer with a "demo" account, or provide a "create account" feature in your app.